# finding geodesics on the surface $z=x^2$

Tags: differential-geometry

Find all the geodesics on the surface $z=x^2$. I found the metric and the Christoffel symbols but i do not know what to do next, any hint ?

Comment: Solve the differential equations? You actually should know the answer, since this is a parabolic cylinder, which can be unrolled (globally) to the plane, where you know all the geodesics.